# How to correctly write @vectorize decorator's signatures with numba

Tags: python, deep-learning, decorator, numba

I want to add a decorator to the function which requires 7 arguments such as:

1. `n = 1000000`
2. `greyscales = np.floor(np.random.uniform(0, 255, n).astype(np.float32))`
3. `weights = np.random.normal(.5, .1, n).astype(np.float32)`
4. `exp`
5. ```
   @vectorize('float32(float32)', target = 'cuda')
   def normalize(greyscales):
       return greyscales / 255
   ```
6. ```
   @vectorize('float32(float32,float32)', target = 'cuda')
   def weigh(values, weights):
       return values * weights
   ```
7. ```
   @vectorize('float32(float32)', target = 'cuda')        
   def activate(values):
       a = exp(values)
       b = exp(-values)
       return (a - b) / (a + b)
   ```

And the function itself looks like this:

```
@vectorize('float32(int,float32,float32,float32,float32,float32,float32)', target='cuda')
def create_hidden_layer(n, greyscales, weights, exp, normalize, weigh, activate):
    normalized = normalize(greyscales)
    weighted = weigh(normalized, weights)
    activated = activate(weighted)
    return activated
```

I got stuck with choosing signatures for @vectorize, especially don't know how to define n and exp. Maybe someone could help me?

Comment: I don't think vectorize allows passing functions around like that, do you really need that? Just calling the vectorized function from another vectorized function should work.

Answer (score 1):

As Rutger Kassies has also said, there does not seem to be a good reason why the create_hidden_layer function has to take the other functions as an input. So you can simply remove that part to make it work,also you should note a couple of other things:

- numba can infer which types a function accepts/outputs, so specifying them is not mandatory.
- "EXP" whatever that means, just use the numpy library exp function, which already has very good performance.

This version of the code should work: (I have removed the cuda part to make it work on my machine):

```
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize

n = 1000000
greyscales = np.floor(np.random.uniform(0, 255, n).astype(np.float32))
weights = np.random.normal(.5, .1, n).astype(np.float32)

@vectorize('float32(float32)')
def normalize(greyscales):
    return greyscales / 255
@vectorize('float32(float32,float32)')
def weigh(values, weights):
    return values * weights
@vectorize('float32(float32)')        
def activate(values):
    a = np.exp(values)
    b = np.exp(-values)
    return (a - b) / (a + b)

@vectorize()
    def create_hidden_layer(n, greyscales, weights):
        normalized = normalize(greyscales)
        weighted = weigh(normalized, weights)
        activated = activate(weighted)
        return activated
    
create_hidden_layer(n, greyscales, weights)
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I'm completely new to this and this create_hidden_layer function is from one of the tasks of the course I'm taking now. The problem is that this function should take less than 1s to run, but it takes 1,2s and thought that adding decorator will work as an improvement to make it run faster...